# Populating template tabs via REST API

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to populate template text tabs, but they just wont populate.

I have created a template, and created a text tab in the template with data label "occupancy"

Here is my request for the [Create Envelope](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/)  Rest API call:

```xml
<envelopeDefinition 
    xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi">
    <emailSubject>Esr Reservation Agreement</emailSubject>
    <status>sent</status>
    <templateId>3a10eb47-4290-4a4b-bd45-240ff2b229cc</templateId>
     <templateRoles>
        <email>testemail@gmail.com</email>
        <name>Test Name</name>
        <roleName>Guest</roleName>
        <tabs>
            <textTabs>
                <tabLabel>occupancy</tabLabel>
                <value>1</value>
            </textTabs>
        </tabs>
    </templateRoles>
</envelopeDefinition>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow. Please accept and upvote the answer if it resolved your issue. If you need more help, please post a comment or a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the **templateRole** node and the **text** node

The following XML should work.

```xml
<envelopeDefinition
    xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi">
  <emailSubject>Esr Reservation Agreement</emailSubject>
  <status>sent</status>
  <templateId>3a10eb47-4290-4a4b-bd45-240ff2b229cc</templateId>
  <templateRoles>
    <templateRole>
      <email>testemail@gmail.com</email>
      <name>Test Name</name>
      <roleName>Guest</roleName>
      <tabs>
        <textTabs>
          <text>
            <tabLabel>occupancy</tabLabel>
            <value>1</value>
          </text>
        </textTabs>
      </tabs>
    </templateRole>
  </templateRoles>
</envelopeDefinition>
```